# calling library functions from GUI in Qt creator

Tags: qt4

I have libraries created from visual studio.I want to use the functions in library in Qt GUI.
How to do that?How to make the GUI understand that it depends on the lib?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this at the code level. Gui is for creating forms/widgets/guis.